# Entitry Framework Add To Intersection Table

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, wcf-data-services

I have a User table and a Group table. Between these is a UserGroups intersection table to allow a user to belong to any number of groups.

The groups table is already populated with values.

How do I add a group to this user so that in the intersection table the relationship between the user and a group is created?

My Primary Keys auto increment.

My DB structure:

[image]

My EF structure:

[image]
<sub>(source: [livefilestore.com](https://cp9ovw.bay.livefilestore.com/y1p_ukGx2dNfTp3iNn3PnZEP38UvaFxvHB2FkLadSFr97c8nHwX8rfFp7AwQ3h29hm1-Rk1QcpOBJlZSdJkUn40rb9PwmUAm8F6/ef.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Looks like i was missing the plot aboit.

the solutions is very simple.

Here is a little examle.

Thanks

```
            using (UserEntities ctx = new UserEntities())
        {

            var group = (from g in ctx.Group
                        select g).FirstOrDefault();

            User user = new User();

            user.UserName = "Ian";

            user.UserGroups.Add(new UserGroups { Group = group });

            ctx.AddToUser(user);

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: how do you add/remove new `UserGroups` after the inserting the user?